# THREE JS floating point precision on translation

Tags: javascript, precision, point, floating

I'm translating my geometry in the Y and X axis and when I console log its position the result I get is something like this:

T…E.Vector3 {x: -25.399999618530273, y: -7.5, z: 0}

I'm only translating my geometry by 0.1 on both axis, yet whenever I test it there's always a slight offset to one of them (in the case above it's the X axis, I was expecting it to be 25.4, not 25.39999...).

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: That's just the way FP arithmetic works - it cannot have infinite precision. Instead, you need to change the way of testing for equality of FP numbers. Instead of `a === b`, check if `Math.abs(a - b) < eps`, where `eps` is a small number, eg. `1e-6`.

Comment: Must read [this tutorial](http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/43) or the golden source, [What every programmer should know about floating point arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) by David Goldberg